# eric6 installed on ubuntu 19.04 causing /usr/bin/python3: Relink `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1'

Tags: 19.04, eric

Recently upgraded from `ubuntu 18.04` to `ubuntu 18.10` to `ubuntu 19.04`: installed `eric` with `sudo apt-get install eric`.

`eric` input results in this output message:

`/usr/bin/python3: relink /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 with /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 for IFUNC symbol clock_gettime 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I've checked elsewhere and numerous reports of similar mesaage however no obvious solution given.

What is the minimum that has to be reinstalled to eliminate this issue?

I did try installing `eric6` from mercurial repo `hg clone https://die-offenbachs.homelinux.org/hg/eric` and that worked in virtual env.  Not something I wanted to do.  What I noticed was the dependencies.  I tried this:

`sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 pyqt5-dev-tools python3-pyside2.qsci python3-pyside2.qtgui python3-pyside2.qtnetwork python3-pyside2.qtprintsupport python3-pyside2.qtsql python3-pyside2.qtsvg python3-pyside2.qtwidgets python3-pyside2.qtwebenginewidgets`

`cd eric/scripts`

`sudo python3 install.py`

The final step does `Compiling user interface files ...` and `Compiling source files ...`
This worked also.